# setText in custom view

Tags: android, text, custom-view

I have created a custom class from a tutorial online. It works fine, but what I want to do is make it so that I can set the text of the view, just like I would any other view. How is that accomplished. Here is the xml for the custom view

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/file_image_holder"
android:layout_width="110dip"
android:layout_height="110dip"
android:src="@drawable/pdf_icon" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/file_name_holder"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="File Name Here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this

```
FileView fileView = new FileView(this)
fileView.setText("text")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TextView filename = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_name_holder);
filename.setText("someFile.exe");
```

On another note ... you can use hint to give your users a greyed out text prompt that they won't have to erase when entering a filename.  In your XML replace `android:text` with `android:hint` for your TextView.

Comment: Do I put that code inside of the custom views class, or in the activity im diong it from?

Comment: The 2 lines of code go in your activity.  The android:hint goes in your XML to replace the android:text in the TextView.

Comment: What im trying to do is make it so I can do this
FileView fileView = new FileView(this)
fileView.setText(this) 
with that code I want it to set the text of the textview within that custom view. I feel that if I do it by the findviewbyid it will have a problem because there is going to be multiple ones in the same layout

Comment: In your example fileView is the whole view, not the TextView.  I do not know how to accomplish what you're trying to do.  Sorry.

Comment: I figured it out. filView is the custom view that holds multiple views. In the code for the customView, just make a method that references the id of the textview within the customview you made, and set the text that way. You were right with your suggestion, just make the setText inside the customview

Comment: @Shaun i am also trying to do the same thing, but i can not setText to the textview, but i can display the already added default text in a toast, did u face anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

replace "File Name Here" with "TEXT YOU WANT" or @string/name_of_string_in_string.xml

or the java way, which someone else answered

Comment: Narhem is right!  It's a good idea to use strings.xml.  You can simplify the process by highlighting the text in your XML and then choosing Extract Android String off the Refactoring -> Android menu.  That will automatically pull your text into your strings file and put the @string/name_of_string_in_string.xml in your XML file.

Comment: Im not trying to do it in xml. I only have text there so that I could see how it looked. Im trying to do it progmmatically.

Answer (score 0):

here no_internet is include xml view . in the include view contain text view. you can set text in include custom text view like ....

```
 no_internet     = view.findViewById(R.id.no_internet);
  ((TextView) no_internet).setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
```