# Set text of included view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, include

I'm wondering if this is possible:

In a layout file, I've included a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/includedView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That includedView contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" >

    <ImageView
    ...
    />

    <TextView
    ....
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is: is it possible to set the text for the textview inside the includedView from the layout that includes the view (so from layout 1)?

Hope my question is clear, if not, then please ask.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you can refer to that view as the whole included layout was copied into the main layout file.

Comment: Yes, as Analizer said, it is possible.....

Comment: but the included layout isn't a textview, the included layout contains a textview. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084869/access-view-of-included-xml-layout

Comment: "but the included layout isn't a textview, the included layout contains a textview. Does that matter?" --- you can refer to the textview using its id as allways, it will be found

Comment: @Analizer Could you make that an answer please?

Comment: do you want to set text from code? or from xml?

Comment: @StinePike Preferably form xml, but code would be okay too.

Comment: for `setText` in custom view use this [see Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31715382/4395114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that from code as same as single layout. for example

```
setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_of_second_layout); // just like single layout
tv.setText(something);
```

But I think it is not possible to do this from the first layout xml as there is no visible way. (someone corrects me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can refer to that view as the whole included layout was copied into the main layout file. You can refer to the textview using its id as allways, it will be found

Comment: You can set it from xml only in the included layout, so it can only be set once, and it will be set to the same value in every layout it is included, so I recommend you to set it from code.

Comment: Okay, and can you just use findViewById() or do you have to use includedView.findViewById()?

Comment: You can do everything in code as the RelativeLayout was not included but copied into the main layout, so you can simply use findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set something in a included view /layout ,like in navigation drawer if you want to set text(profile name,email etc), then do it like below.

```
NavigationView mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);

TextView profilename = headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
TextView emailtxt = headerView.findViewById(R.id.email_txt);
```